# PHPUnit version/author line output

Tags: phpunit

Is there a way of disabling output of version line of PHPUnit? Line that says `PHPUnit <version> by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`.

I'm writing a wrapper for phpunit CLI invocation with XML printer, and I'm getting output of

```
PHPUnit 6.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
 ... rest of the xml
```

which I need to trim just to get to XML. Can I just disable output of that version-copyright line?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do? What CLI command are you executing?

Comment: @AleksanderWons that doesn't really matter what command I'm trying to execute, copyright line is printed on every command execution. I'm trying to get XML output ONLY, without having copyright header on top of it, but seems there's no flags for phpunit to be less verbose and it's really sad, since I'd assume that when someone is specifically using printer to get output in a specific format - why there would be anything not in that format?

Comment: So to answer your question directly - no, there is no way to disable version string. Call to it is hardcoded in both `PHPUnit\TextUI\Command` and `PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner` class. But you can still extract the XML with simple `strpos` and `substr`.

Comment: @AleksanderWons thanks for the info. There is indeed no problem in extracting XML, but that's quite strange for a tool to force an additional output, even when the output is set to be in a specified format. I guess I'll file up an issue at phpunit's github, though I don't think it will matter, since it seems I'm the only one having a problem with that.

Comment: Another option is to file an issue and submit a PR ;) Not sure if Sebastian will agree with it, though.